# Azure Function using Selenium WebDriver.dll

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-functions

i am trying to use Selenium WebDriver.dll from Azure Function C# code and having following issue when instantiating WebDriver.

**Error:**

> 2017-10-16T20:02:25.169 Exception while executing function: Functions.fnTestSelenium. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. mscorlib: The path is not of a legal form.2017-10-16T20:02:25.278 Function completed (Failure, Id=2fcb928f-ee39-4cfe-99f2-4be2d57e91b2, Duration=843ms)

**Code**

**`#r` "D:\home\site\wwwroot\fnTestSelenium\bin\WebDriver.dll"
using System.Net;**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    IWebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Set name to query string or body data
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}
```

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your code as code, error message with a comment (>) tag, remove the heading style, etc. so that it's more easily read.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you'll have much success running Selenium on Azure Functions.

Azure Functions, like WebApps and Mobile Apps, run in an App Service. The App Service runs in a secure environment called a sandbox which imposes certain limitation. Amongst them, is the use of GDI+.

You can see the list of limitation, along with the list of unsupported frameworks https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

If you check towards the bottom, you will see Selenimum in the list of unsupported:

> Other scenarios that are not supported:
>
> PhantomJS/**Selenium**: tries to connect to local address, and also uses
>   GDI+.

Comment: I can run selenium bot using Azure function on my local machine but on live server it fails. What is the difference? Why it runs locally at first place?

Comment: In local you have the complete access. App service is a shared environment and as mentioned  above the app service sandbox doesnt allow it. If you want to run it in app service, try to run images in app service