# Deploy Python Web Scraping files on Azure cloud(function apps)

Tags: python, azure, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have 2 python files that do Web scraping using Selenium and Beautifulsoup and store the results in separate CSV files say file1.csv and file2.csv. Now, I want to deploy these files on the Azure cloud, I know Azure function apps will be ideal for this. But, I don't know how Functions app will support Selenium driver on it.

Basically, I want to time trigger my 2 web scraping files and store the results in two separate files file1.csv and file2.csv that will be stored in blob storage on Azure cloud. Can someone help me with this task?

How can I use the selenium driver on Azure functions app?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778220/azure-function-using-selenium-webdriver-dll?rq=1

Comment: No, it does not answer my question. I have already read all the articles present on the web. But, none seem to solve this problem. I thought maybe someone might have done it. But it seems deploying on VM is the only option left for this task. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying on virtual machines or EC2 is the only option that one can use to achieve this task.

Also, with Heroku, we will be able to run selenium on the cloud by adding buildpacks. But when it comes to storing the files, we will not be able to store files on heroku as heroku does not persist the files. So, VMs or EC2 instances are the only options for this task.